# How to Write Two Dimensional List to file

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm currently trying to write a program where after the values taken from a User input for a Golf Data Sheet would have each record written to file with their Names and Statistics stored as separate individual records that could access the numerical values in a second program later. Unfortunately I've run into a roadblock where I cannot get these to store to file. What would I need to enter?

This is for a new Python File, in which the file would be storing the data. I can verify I have managed to make the program already store each field to an individual record with the information, however I cannot seem to have it all be written to a file, somehow.

```py
golf_data = []
run_loop = 0

while run_loop != 16:
    main_data = []
    inner_loop = 0
    while inner_loop != 1:
        fname = input("Entry First Name: ")
        lname = input("Entry Last Name: ")
        handicap = float(input("Handicap value: "))
        score = float(input("Enter the Score: "))
        main_data.append(fname)
        main_data.append(lname)
        main_data.append(handicap)
        main_data.append(score)
        golf_data.append(main_data)
        inner_loop += 1
    run_loop += 1


outfile = open('golf.txt', 'w')
for element in golf_data:
    outfile.write(element + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

I expect the file to store the results inputted by the User, however instead I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:/Users/joelc/PycharmProjects/Project2/File/JoelLab5Pt1.py", line 24, in <module>
     outfile.write(element + '\n')

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: `outfile.write(",".join(element) + '\n')`. You need to convert `element` to string.

Comment: If you have numpy, then you can also do `numpy.savtxt("golf_data.txt", golf_data)`, which directly writes your array to file without you having to do it manually via a file handler.

Comment: I had tried to convert the values, however I have now run into another error, unfortunately. 


```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joelc/PycharmProjects/Project2/File/JoelLab5Pt1.py", line 24, in <module>
    outfile.write(",".join(element) + '\n')
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found
```

While I could choose to directly use numpy, my assignment requires I only utilize the programming in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
golf_data = []
run_loop = 0

while run_loop != 16:
    main_data = []
    inner_loop = 0
    while inner_loop != 1:
        fname = input("Entry First Name: ")
        lname = input("Entry Last Name: ")
        handicap = float(input("Handicap value: "))
        score = float(input("Enter the Score: "))
        main_data.append(fname)
        main_data.append(lname)
        main_data.append(handicap)
        main_data.append(score)
        golf_data.append(main_data)
        inner_loop += 1
    run_loop += 1

outfile = open('golf.txt', 'w')
for element in golf_data:
    outfile.write(",".join((str(x) for x in element)) + '\n')

outfile.close()
```